# Несколько обращений к MySQL из Shell скрипта

Tags: shell, centos, mysql

Пишу shell скрипт на CentOS, нужно сделать несколько запросов в БД из скрипта

```
#!/bin/bash
re=`mysql -h'localhost' -u'ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ' -p'ПАРОЛЬ' -b 'БАЗАДАННЫХ'`
//какой-то код
$re -> "MySQL ЗАПРОС"
//какой-то код
$re -> "MySQL ЗАПРОС (ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ИЗ SHELL)"
//какой-то код
$re -> "MySQL ЗАПРОС"
//какой-то код
$re -> "MySQL ЗАПРОС (ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ИЗ SHELL)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

P="password"
U="user"
B="base"

echo "select * from table1" | mysql -u $U --password=$P $B
echo "select * from table2" | mysql -u $U --password=$P $B
```

Comment: думаю не совсем так, я хочу один раз настроить и потом просто делать запросы через функцию:
mysql = НАСТРОЙКИ
//код
ЗАПРОС | mysql
//код
ЗАПРОС | mysql
//код
ЗАПРОС | mysql

Comment: Что не так? Прописываете все переменные в скрипте, и потом сколько угодно их используете в любых запросах. 


Или пишите на чём-нибудь вроде Perl/DBI.


P.S. Подредактировал пример, теперь "с настройками"